# How to enable listening 10255 in my kubelet service

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, metricbeat

I am learning to work with Kubernetes and trying to configure monitoring of my Kubernetes cluster. For this I use metricbeat and elk.
After deploying and configuring metricbeat, I get an error:

```
error making http request: Get http://172.16.0.205:10255/stats/summary: dial tcp 172.16.0.205:10255: connect: connection refused
```

I found that my Kubelet is not listening on port 10255:

```
[root@kube2 /]# netstat -ap | grep -i "listen" | grep "kubelet"
tcp        0      0 localhost:40450         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8560/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 localhost:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8560/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:10250              [::]:*                  LISTEN      8560/kubelet
```

How can I enable this port. I found information that I need to use the parameter --read-only-port = 10255, but how do I apply it to my kubelet, I do not quite understand. For example:

```
[root@kube2 /]# kubelet --config --read-only-port=10255
\F1010 13:32:48.592306   15851 server.go:196] failed to load Kubelet config file --read-only-port=10255, error failed to read kubelet config file "/--read-only-port=10255", error: open /--read-only-port=10255: no such file or directory
```

It's does't work. Which file does it need?

Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem?

Comment: I tried to add lines to kubelet.conf:

    spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kubelet
    - --read-only-port=10255

And restart kubelet service, but that doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue. I added flags in /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-flags in every my kubertenes' nodes:

```
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--cgroup-driver=systemd --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 --read-only-port=10255"
```

and restart kubelet service.

Now I have open port 10255:

```
[root@kube2 7.1]# netstat -ap | grep -i "listen" | grep "kubelet"
tcp        0      0 localhost:44799         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6281/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 localhost:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6281/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:10250              [::]:*                  LISTEN      6281/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 [::]:10255              [::]:*                  LISTEN      6281/kubelet
```

And I see some logs of kubernetes in my kibana.